# Link tap opens the Android browser and quits the app

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I develop an app for Android with **Sencha Touch** and **Phonegap** (cordova-2.0.0).

I have an Ext.Panel with some HTML in it, For Instance:

```html
<body>
     <a href="MyPage.html">MyPage</a>
</body>
```

**My Problem**: When I run the app on device and tap the link, Android browser opens the URL and it quits the app.

**My Aim**: When I run the app on device and tap the link, the app should show the tapped link, For Instance:

`navigator.notification.alert(MyPage.html);`

**My Phonegap code**(shows the uniqueid.html in the HTMLPanel):

```html
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystemSuccess, null);

function onRequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#bibliothekDataView')[0].getSelection()[0].get('directory'), null, SelectedItemSuccess, SelectedItemFail);
}

//shows the uniqueid.html in the HTMLPanel
function SelectedItemSuccess(dir) {
    dir.getFile(record.get('id') + '.html', null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function SelectedItemFail() {
    navigator.notification.alert("Failed to read file contents: " + error.code);
}

function gotFileEntry(file) {
    file.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file) {
    readAsText(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#mainHTMLPanel')[0].setHtml(evt.target.result);
    };

    reader.onerror = function () {
        navigator.notification.alert("Failed to read file!");
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Failed to read file contents: " + error.code);
}
```

**My HTMLPanel** (View):

```html
Ext.define('myApp.view.HTMLPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainhtmlpanel',

    config: {
        id: 'mainHTMLPanel',
        scrollable: 'vertical',
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to register an Intent, to catch the intent and open the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have control over HTML content displayed in Ext.Panel? If yes, then change `<a href="MyPage.html">MyPage</a>` to `<a href="javascript:alert('MyPage.html');">MyPage</a>`.

Comment: it seems to be the simplest solution for me, THX